# Offering an iOS Subscription Across Multiple Apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

Does anyone have experience implementing this in their apps? I wasn't able to find very much documentation on this topic. It looks like even RevenueCat hasn't implemented this yet. I did find a Google-cached page that contains a question asking whether they will support this. The response was that it's on their radar. But that page has since been removed leading me to believe they have abandoned this plan.

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/offering_a_subscription_across_multiple_apps):

> When providing auto-renewable subscription access across multiple
> apps, you must authenticate the user in a way that can be correlated
> across apps. Authenticating users via a login allows you to determine
> if the user has access to the content. The login process should be
> consistent across your apps.

But if you have this, what is the added value of this new subscriptions-across-apps feature? One could already implement subscriptions across apps this way. Is there some special identifier that links the subscriptions on Apple's side that allows users in app B to restore subscription purchased in app A?

Comment: I also have a slightly differently worded version of this question on the Apple Developer Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653350#653350021

Comment: Did you find any solution or way to share the identifier across the applications in the same bundle?